# How to extract numbers in bracket with regex

Tags: regex, matlab

May I know how to extract the numbers within a bracket using `regex` Matlab

```
str='eeg_eegrej( EEG, [263668 263936] )'
```

The expected should be

> 263668 ,
> 263936

I tried as below

```
regexp(str, '(?<=\([[^)]*(?=\])', 'match')
```

but, return empty string

Comment: Not sure what regex flavor matlab uses, but what about: `regexp(str, '(\d+) (\d+)', 'match')`, or possibly `regexp(str, '(\d+ \d+)', 'match')` depending on how the desired match should appear? (as 2 matched values, or 1 match)

Comment: Thanks @PaulT. for future reader: newStr = split( regexp(str, '(\d+ \d+)', 'match') );
s1= str2double(newStr{1});
s2= str2double(newStr{2});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your look-around assertions are almost right, but I think you've over-complicated it, you can use this pattern `'(?<=[)\d+ \d+(?=])'`, as in

```
>> str = 'eeg_eegrej( EEG, [263668 263936] )';
>> nums = regexp( str, '(?<=[)\d+ \d+(?=])', 'match', 'once' )
nums =
    '263668 263936'
```

Even better though would be to include the brackets, then you can use `str2num` to get an array out

```
>> str = 'eeg_eegrej( EEG, [263668 263936] )';
>> nums = str2num( regexp( str, '\[\d+ \d+\]', 'match', 'once' ) )
nums =
      [263668, 263936]
```

If there was no match in this 2nd case then `nums` would be an empty array, otherwise it will be a 2-element array.

Answer (score 1):

I have some suggestions that work for your example, but they don't strictly enforce that they parse numbers between square brackets.

Starting in 20b, MATLAB has pattern.

If your problem allows it, you can extract digits using digitsPattern without needed regexp. If the input to extract is a string then the output will be a string and you can just call double to convert it to numeric.

```
>> str = 'eeg_eegrej( EEG, [263668 263936] )';
>> str = string(str);
>> nums = double(extract(str, digitsPattern))

nums =

      263668
      263936
```

And if you're okay grabbing anything between the square brackets, you can use the following code inspired by Wolfie's answer:

```
>> str = 'eeg_eegrej( EEG, [263668 263936] )';
>> str = string(str);
​>> str2num(extractBetween(str,"[","]"))

​ans =

      ​263668      26393
```

To convert text to a number, I think calling double on a string is fastest, followed by str2double, followed by str2num. However, since they behave differently, there are some pros/cons to each depending on your use case.